# SSRS need SUM of 2 columns out of 3 grouped columns in matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I want to get the sum of 2 columns. The 3 columns shown are in column grouping and I need to get SUM of two columns only:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMLj1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column to your tablix and add the following expression in the detail section textbox of this column:

```
=Fields!SanStorageEconomy.Value + Fields!SanStorageEnterprise.Value
```

Comment: Hello, i do no have these columns in my query so i cannot use fields!column.value. As i said it is grouped column so in my query it is only 1 coumn with SanStorageEconomy, SanStorageEnterprise, localstorage rows values

Comment: You have three columsn in your picture. These three columns should be in your dataset. And above is the code example how to reference to this columns. If this is inclear you could send more information about your report. How does the dataset look? What are your expressions? How does the tablix look in design mode?

Comment: i changed my SQL query to get all 3 colums from rows using PIVOT function and resolved issue